# Change the size of a button in gwidgets2 size<-function giving error

Tags: r, button, size

The button is created looks like this

[image]

The button position is full screen and when I add more its comming in one row.

Secondly I can't change its size using size function I tried following:

```
size(b1)<-list("width" = 500, "height" = 20)
```

Its giving error:

> Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") :
> [tcl] unknown option "-height".

When I tried `b1$set_size(20,10)` its not giving error but not changing size.

Comment: That is how things expand: horizontal groups have top to bottom expansion, vertical boxes have side-to-side expansion. Try adding with `expand=FALSE`.

Comment: @jverzani didn't work

Comment: Okay, I was just guessing and didn't very. Compare this: `w = gwindow(); h = ggroup(horizontal=TRUE, cont=w); b = gbutton("Hi", cont=h)` to w = gwindow(); v=ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, cont=w); b = gbutton("Hi", cont=v)`. The button expands to fill the horizontal box vertically, and the vertical box horizontally. Nesting can help control this, as in: `w = gwindow(); h = ggroup(horizontal=TRUE, cont=w); v=ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, cont=h); b = gbutton("Hi", cont=v)`.